# nested for-each loops in xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XML. I'm trying to create table containing item details and another table to contain customer details for each order on a picklist. It seems like it should be straightforward but I just get a list of all items on all orders repeated by the number of orders. What am I doing wrong? (XSL code below...)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="css/text" href="style.css"/>
<title>Orders</title>
</head>

<body>
<xsl:for-each select="//order">
<table>
<caption><h3>Order Information</h3></caption>
<thead>
<th align="left">Item Id</th>
<th align="left">Item Description</th>
<th align="left">Quantity</th>
<th align="left">Price</th>
</thead>
<xsl:for-each select="//item">
<tr>
<td align="left"><xsl:value-of select="itemId"/></td>
<td align="left"><xsl:value-of select="itemName"/></td>
<td align="left"><xsl:value-of select="quantity"/></td>
<td align="left"><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
<table>
<caption><h3>Customer Information</h3></caption>
<thead>
<th align="left">Customer Name</th>
<th align="left">Street</th>
<th align="left">City</th>
</thead>
<xsl:for-each select="//item">
<tr>
<td align="left"><xsl:value-of select="customerName"/></td>
<td align="left"><xsl:value-of select="street"/></td>
<td align="left"><xsl:value-of select="city"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Orders.xsl"?>

<orders xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Orders.xsd">
<order>
<orderId>123</orderId>
<items>
<item>
<itemId>001</itemId>
<itemName>Nylon Rope</itemName>
<quantity>1</quantity>
<price>3.50</price>
</item>
<item>
<itemId>002</itemId>
<itemName>Shovel</itemName>
<quantity>1</quantity>
<price>24.95</price>
</item>
</items>
<customerAddress>
<customerName>Larry Murphy</customerName>
<street>Shallowgrave Lane</street>
<city>Ballymore Eustace, Co. Kildare</city>
</customerAddress>
</order>
<order>
<orderId>124</orderId>
<items>
<item>
<itemId>001</itemId>
<itemName>Whiskey</itemName>
<quantity>1</quantity>
<price>18.50</price>
</item>
<item>
<itemId>002</itemId>
<itemName>Shotgun</itemName>
<quantity>1</quantity>
<price>225</price>
</item>
<item>
<itemId>003</itemId>
<itemName>Cartridge</itemName>
<quantity>1</quantity>
<price>1.85</price>
</item>
</items>
<customerAddress>
<customerName>Enda Kenny</customerName>
<street>A Avenue</street>
<city>Castlebar, Co. Mayo</city>
</customerAddress>
</order>
</orders>
```

Relevant XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:element name="orders">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" ref="order"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="order">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" ref="items"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="customerAddress"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="items">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" ref="item"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="item">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" ref="itemId"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" ref="itemName"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" ref="quantity"/>
<xsd:element maxoccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" ref="price"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="customerAddress">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="customerName"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="street"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="city"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="itemId" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="itemName" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="quantity" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element name="price" type="xsd:double"/>
<xsd:element name="customerName" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string"/>

</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:for-each select="//order">
```

selects all the `<order>` tags in the document.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//item">
```

will similarly select all the `<item>` tags in the document. This is why you get the result that you see.

What you need is

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//item">
```

The explanation is that `//` on its own simply means `descendant-or-self` of the root element. `.//` on the other hand means descendant or self of the current element (in this case an `<order>` element), so now your items will be correctly grouped.

You can (and indeed should) read more about this [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#abbrev), understanding axes and context nodes is crucial to understanding how XSLT/XPath works and will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: or even better `<xsl:for-each select="items/item" />`

Comment: @Pawel Of course, it's a good idea to avoid the `descendant-or-self` axis altogether if you can. But let's take learning one step at a time :)

Comment: @biziclop Thanks a million; been tearing hair & biting monitor over this one... that worked ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use // - this way you always select all elements from the xml document instead of ones that are just related to the context node.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this (not tested, maybe also replace two inner loops with template/apply-templates):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="css/text" href="style.css" />
                <title>Orders</title>
            </head>

            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//order" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//order">
        <table>
            <caption>
                <h3>Order Information</h3>
            </caption>
            <thead>
                <th align="left">Item Id</th>
                <th align="left">Item Description</th>
                <th align="left">Quantity</th>
                <th align="left">Price</th>
            </thead>
            <xsl:for-each select="//item">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <xsl:value-of select="itemId" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <xsl:value-of select="itemName" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <xsl:value-of select="quantity" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <xsl:value-of select="price" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        <table>
            <caption>
                <h3>Customer Information</h3>
            </caption>
            <thead>
                <th align="left">Customer Name</th>
                <th align="left">Street</th>
                <th align="left">City</th>
            </thead>
            <xsl:for-each select="//item">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <xsl:value-of select="customerName" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <xsl:value-of select="street" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <xsl:value-of select="city" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I usually use templates for reusability:

```
<xsl:template match="Menu">
<xsl:template match="MenuItem">
```

and then wherever I need them:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/MenuRoot/Menu" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="/MenuRoot/MenuItem" />
```

In your case you could use `match="/order/item"` and `match="/order/customer/item"` (just wild guesses for the structure), try to be more specific.